# translate my code to a batch file for me

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I need to write a batch file which run automatically at particular time of day and i got many solutions from forums which are working fine but in my case i need to write SQL query which is quite complex i state my c# code which i need to run and i need it in SQL query

My C# code is looking as:

```
public void mark_absent()
        {
            int userid = 0, Last_rec = Last_Record();
            bool isapproved;


            cmd = new SqlCommand("select top(1) UserID,IsApproved from tblUser ", conn);
            conn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {

                userid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserID"].ToString());
                isapproved = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["IsApproved"].ToString());

                dr.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                dr.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }

            for (int i = userid; i <= Last_rec; i++)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserID,IsApproved from tblUser where UserID='" + userid + "' and IsApproved='True'", conn);
                conn.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserID,AtnDate from tblAttend where convert(date,AtnDate)='" + DateTime.Now.Date + "' and UserID='" + userid + "'", conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        dr.Close();
                        //count++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblAttend (AtnDate,CheckIn,ChkOut,Status,Workhrs,ExtraHrs,UserID,CrtUpDate) values ('" + DateTime.Now + "','00:00:00','00:00:00','Absent','00:00:00','-09:00:00','" + userid + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')", conn);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    dr.Close();

                }
                userid = userid + 1;

            }
        }
```

In batch file i found only select or delete or insert command but here i need sqldatareader as well as looping

so how can i write this c# code in SQL query. If i am wrong than what is best solution you people will suggest me...?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking how to run SQL in C#, how to execute a program from a batch file, how to schedule a batch file or a program for periodic execution?

Comment: To simply schedule something, use the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: No in need to create procedure that will work as similar as this mentioned code worked...

Comment: Well, that's not at all what the subject of your question says, did I mention that your question was unclear?

Comment: When you say "batch file", could you explain exactly what you mean by that? For me, a batch file is a .bat file out on disk that runs command line programs. I take it you perhaps mean a query batch executed with SQL Server?

Comment: i know how to operate batch file... i need to  write sql procedure which i will further call from batch file... and stored procedure will be alternative of my c# code...Now its clear or not?

Comment: so it's a "please translate my code to a batchfile for me" question?

Comment: @Stephan, you are right

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not "do my work for me" service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution, since you already have working C# code, is to create a Console Application, and use your existing code in the Main() method.

Compile it into an EXE, and place the EXE somewhere on the computer where the code must run.

Use Windows Task Scheduler to schedule your EXE to run as needed.

Make sure you add logging so you can keep track of any errors that happen when the program runs unattended.  NLog is a good place to start.

Comment: this is what i have already an idea but i need expert opinion and suggestions so in my console application i need to give connection of that particular database... am i write ?

Comment: Typically you would put the actual connection string in the Connection Strings section of app.config, and load it in your EXE from the config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run an application at a specific time each day, and you are using a Microsoft OS, look into the Windows Task Scheduler.  You can set a schedule and an action.  The action will be to execute your program.

Comment: I need to convert my code into SQL procedure.

Comment: Can you update your post title to reflect that?  It is not clear that you are asking for help on converting your code to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`sqlcmd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

Example in bacth:

```
sqlcmd -Q "EXEC dbo.your_sp" -S server -d db -o C:\output.txt
```

see [Create a Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx)