# How to fix "Failed to update database" in c# console application?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, console-application

I created and application in c# windows forms and according to system requirements i need to run a program daily at particular time of day to update database,

so for this purpose i write a program in console application suggestion given me in my yesterday's question [translate my code to a batch file for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593168/translate-my-code-to-a-batch-file-for-me).

i connect my c# deployed database in console application to update database at particular time of day but it gave me error that

Failed to update database "Path/DATABASENAME" because the database is read-only.

I tried this but not got any success

```
ALTER DATABASE [DB_Name] SET READ_WRITE
```

and i also set permission to user.

So i need your help to complete my project.
Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Is the path for the database c:\program files? UAC might be blocking you.

Comment: @JamesZ, Yes it is ..

Comment: @JamesZ, path of my database which i need to call is C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT\LEAVESMANAGEMENT\EMPATTENDANCE.MDF"

Comment: Change the directory permissions where your DB exists and ALTER DATABASE [DB_Name] SET READ_WRITE WITH NO_WAIT to check if you got any error whiole executing  ALTER DATABASE [DB_Name] SET READ_WRITE. If it shows that its already in use then put database in single user mode.

Comment: it give me this error "User does not have permission to alter database 'EMPATTENDANCE.MDF', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks."

Comment: [/file-write-permission-issue-under-program-files-folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191941/file-write-permission-issue-under-program-files-folder) This might help you.

Comment: @Waqas Well move your datatabase somewhere else. Program files is not meant for storing application data

Comment: Thanks for your time, I got the solution by Under Object Explorer, right-click on your  Database  - >  Properties - > State - >  Database Read - Only - > True/False

Comment: @JamesZ,this is just for testing my application on my machine only. on client machine i will change it . Thanks for time and suggestions.